# ng-include not including template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm following a Code School tutorial on Angular.  I'm trying to include a template with ng-include.  I have the following code:

```
<h3 ng-include="'product-title.html'"></h3>
```

and my `product-title.html`

```
{{product.name}}
<em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
```

When I inspect the element it shows `<!-- ngInclude: 'product-title.html' -->`

Question.  Do I need to be running a web server in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to run your application from a server. Templates are loaded via AJAX call, and those calls need to originate from a webserver.

You have several lightweight options to run an ad-hoc static files servers, e.g.:

- node's `simple-server` (https://github.com/balupton/simple-server)
- python's `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`